# Why does system() exist?

Tags: c

Many papers and such mention that calls to 'system()' are unsafe and unportable. I do not dispute their arguments.

I have noticed, though, that many Unix utilities have a C library equivalent. If not, the source is available for a wide variety of these tools.

While many papers and such recommend against `goto`, there are those who can make an argument for its use, and there are simple reasons why it's in C at all.

So, why do we need `system()`? How much existing code relies on it that can't easily be changed?

Comment: Calls to `system()` can be fantastically useful, even if they are also nonportable and theoretically unsafe.

Comment: example: `system("cls");`

Comment: `system()` ispart of the standard library. It is the *only* portable way to perform system-specific stuff. Of course, the string argument should make sense for the particular environment, but that cannot be not imposed by the C standard.

Comment: Keep in mind that the primary goal of ISO C was to *codify existing practice*, and at the time (1989), most if not all compilers provided a `system()` library function.

Comment: Also, in closed source days, it allowed some things to be configurable by the user, *without recompilation*. For Unix, External (shell)scripts could be used to configure terminal lines/modems, which could be *very* system-specific. Filters for LPD used to be shell scripts, too.

Comment: Goes back to the olden days, C, unix and shell were paper, rock and scissors.  The shell never had a blessed api, mostly because there always was more than one, system() was the backdoor.  It still is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to an official "why" answer you're likely to find is the C89 Rationale. *4.10.4.5 The system function* reads:

> The system function allows a program to suspend its execution temporarily in order to run another program to completion.
>
> Information may be passed to the called program in three ways: through command-line argument strings, through the environment, and (most portably) through data files.  Before calling the system function, the calling program should close all such data files.
>
> Information may be returned from the called program in two ways: through the implementation-defined return value (in many implementations, the termination status code which is the argument to the exit function is returned by the implementation to the caller as the value returned by the system function), and (most portably) through data files.
>
> If the environment is interactive, information may also be exchanged with users of interactive devices.
>
> Some implementations offer built-in programs called *"commands"*  (for example, `date`)  which may provide useful information to an application program via the system function.  The Standard does not attempt to characterize such commands, and their use is not portable.
>
> On the other hand, the use of the system function is portable, provided the implementation supports the capability.  The Standard permits the application to ascertain this by calling the system function with a null pointer argument.  Whether more levels of nesting are supported can also be ascertained this way; assuming more than one such level is obviously dangerous.

Aside from that, I would say mainly for historical reasons. In the early days of Unix and C, `system` was a convenient library function that fulfilled a need that several interactive programs needed: as mentioned above, "suspend[ing] its execution temporarily in order to run another program". It's not well-designed or suitable for any serious tasks (the POSIX requirements for it make it fundamentally non-thread-safe, it doesn't admit asynchronous events to be handled by the calling program while the other program is running, etc.) and its use is error-prone (safe construction of command string is difficult) and non-portable (because the particular form of command strings is implementation-defined, though POSIX defines this for POSIX-conforming implementations).

If C were being designed today, it almost certainly would not include `system`, and would either leave this type of functionality entirely to the implementation and its library extensions, or would specify something more akin to `posix_spawn` and related interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

*sarcastic answer* Because if it didn't exist people would ask why that functionality didn't exist...

*better answer*
Many of the system functionality is not part of the 'C' standard but are part of say the Linux spec and Windows most likely has some equivalent. So if you're writing an app that will only be used on Linux environments then using these functions is not an issue, and as such is actually useful. If you're writing an application that can run on both Linux and Windows (or others) these calls become problematic because they may not be portable between system. The key (imo) is that you are simply aware of the issues/concerns and program accordingly (e.g. use appropriate #ifdef's to protect the code etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Many interactive applications offer a way for users to execute shell commands. For instance, in `vi` you can do:

```
:!ls
```

and it will execute the `ls` command. `system()` is a function they can use to do this, rather than having to write their own `fork()` and `exec()` code.

Also, `fork()` and `exec()` aren't portable between operating systems; using `system()` makes code that executes shell commands more portable.