# Why does system() still exist?

Tags: c++

I am aware of this question: [Why does system() exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866536/why-does-system-exist)
But the accepted answer refers to C89, a 30 year old standard, which won't really help me. As far as I know, `system()` is a resource intensive security flaw, in addition to not being portable across operating systems. Even if there is a legitimate reason to for the functionality, I don't believe there's anything stopping me from writing `system("rm -rf /*")`. Generally a 1 liner to delete nearly everything is probably not a great language feature. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/) article proclaims it to be evil for quite a few reasons.

In the question linked above a comment states that system "is the only portable way to perform system-specific stuff." This doesn't make sense to me, the code I write with system for some Linux distro won't work on a Windows machine. It also seems that "portable system-specific" is an oxymoron. And aren't there APIs to talk to the machine such as `windows.h`?

So is there a legitimate reason for system to continue existing, are there legacy applications, or has C++ just not got around to axing it?

Comment: Letting `system` execute arbitrary commands is different than letting it execute arbitrary *user* commands. You could have string literals in your program that you `#ifdef` or whatever based on windows vs linux, etc.

Comment: "Portable" as in [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)?

Comment: You can also remove files with the c++ filesystem library, that's even a portable way to delete files. Or you could just call OS-specific functions. Removing `system()` won't be stopping anyone from writing harmful code. Probably it's kept for backwards compatibility? Because some programs actually use it in a good way.

Comment: would you say `fstream` is not portable, because when I pass it a filename I need `\ ` between directories on one system and `/` on another system? See the analogy?

Comment: *Why* does it still exist? Because it existed in the past and taking it away would break a lot of code (and you can do the same with other tools *anyway*).  Should you *use it* in new code? No, of course not. Should you try to remove it from old code? Certainly.

Comment: @idclev463035818 FYI, Windows operating systems accept the forward slash, `'/'`, as a folder or directory separator (provided there are no spaces preceding).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I didnt specify the OS because I knew I would have gotten it wrong ;). Not writing any code for windows, I just remembered that there is a difference. Thanks anyhow

Comment: btw if someone claims something is "evil" i would be careful. Exaggeration is often a sign for not having good arguments (not always, but often). The article you link mainly describes what is bad about misusing `system`. I mean `system("PAUSE")` and `system("CLS")`.... come on, of course that is "evil". Other than that the article refers to the manual which mentions what you have to be careful about and to "what it really does" and then calls that "evil". That is bad style imho. A hammer is not evil because you can hit your finger with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove `system()` what security do you gain? You can achieve the same thing with `fork()` and `exec()`, which is all that `system()` does internally.

Any program you're running on your machine you must either *trust* or *sandbox*. In a sandboxed environment one of the first things to go is a working `system()` call, but other things are also disabled as well, necessarily.

Running external programs is an important function that cannot be removed.

Remember that one of the defining principles of C++ is that the language will never presume to be smarter than the programmer and won't prevent the programmer from doing whatever they want, regardless of the consequences.

There's no reason to remove it as you can always implement it with other tools.

Comment: Also, if you don't use it, it doesn't add any code to your executable.  So, it's fine to let it be.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Exactly. It's not exploitable unless your code has an RCE, and if your code does you've got way bigger problems than someone being able to trigger `system()`. "Someone broke into my house, which means they have access to *the microwave*!"

Comment: @tadman This is not entirely true. With `system`, you can do `system ("myscript.bat")` or `system ("myscript.sh")` which is difficult, even impossible with `fork, createprocess, ...`

Comment: @Landstalker Not at all. You just `exec` a shell and pass it in arguments. That's all `system` does. Just look at [how `system()` is implemented](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/procexec/system.c.html) and look at the `execl` shell call.

Comment: @Landstalker The Windows non-POSIX library presumably has a different implementation. If they publish the source, have a look.

Comment: @tadman according to my knowledge, there is not a REAL implementation of `fork`, with the notion of parent, child, cloning of data, descriptors, ... you have several variants `createprocess, ShellExecute, ...` but it is not really a `fork`

Comment: @Landstalker You don't need `fork` to implement `system()` but that's just the easiest method on POSIX. On Windows you do might something different.